# Javascript - File drop on SVG triggers ondragleave instead of ondrop

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm trying to trigger the drop event on an SVG circle put in a div (where I also call the events `ondragover`, `ondragleave` and `ondrop` and everything works well).
The `ondragover` and `ondragleave` events on the circle works fine, but the `ondrop` event triggers the `ondragleave` instead of `ondrop`. Other than that, when I drag over an image on the circle, the mouse pointer shows me that I can't drop it there with the "blocked" pointer.
I don't know what it could be for the first problem, but for the second could it be that I filled the circle with an image and it can't drop images over another images? I already tried to use `event.preventDefault()`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call preventDefault() in the dragover (ondragover) event handler.

**Example:**

```js
let svg = document.getElementById('svg')
svg.addEventListener('dragover', e => { e.preventDefault(); console.log('dragover') })
svg.addEventListener('dragleave', () => { console.log('dragleave') })
svg.addEventListener('drop', e => { e.preventDefault(); console.log('drop') })
```

```html
<div>
  <img id="svg" width="200" height="200" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/Circle_-_black_simple.svg">
</div>
<hr>
<img width="200" height="200" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/91/Fxemoji_u1F431.svg">
```

**Another example:** https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp